# Is there any tool or API to visualize NAnt build scripts?

Tags: nant, visualizer

I have a complex [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) build script, which contains a lot of `*.build` and `*.include` files with many targets inside, which in their turn are called both via `depends` and via `call`. I'd like to have a visual representation in a tree-like form of what calls what. It should also be an easy way to regenerate it because the script is growing further.

Is there any ready-made tool or some API (preferably .NET-based) I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

There's [NAntBuilder](http://www.polestarsoft.com/products/nantbuilder/) although it seems to be expensive (with a free trial). I've never used it personally so I couldn't recommend it either way.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found one, but my general mantra is "get your designer out of my face".  Imagine a database diagram in Sql Management Studio or in the EF Design Surface if you've got 30 or 50 tables.  Generally my mental map is better organized.

Probably the best way to initially visualize the dependencies is to run the build and watch the task names appear in the output.